# Web-based InfoPath form that "vanish" after submit in SharePoint 2007 Library

Tags: infopath, web-services, error, library

I have a problem with my InfoPath form in my SharePoint 2007 library.

The InfoPath form is a web enable and will open in the browser.

However, after submit the InfoPath form, and click that link pointing to the InfoPath form that just created, I will receive the following error from SharePoint 2007 Library:

`Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.`

Also, the infopath form that is submitted will "vanish" or cease to be exist inside the Sharepoint 2007 library.

Is there ways (preferable as many ways as possible) to diagnose and solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a check on my InfoPath form and notice that actually, the problem was caused by the permission setting.

In my form, there is a field that keep track of the user who had log on. Then my workflow will use this field and apply the respectively permission to this user.

However, what happen was that the domain of the user was not insert. That is why the workflow "auto" delete my form. (e.g. Suppose the domain is "Finance" and the user is "John", I need to have the field that contain "Finance\John" instead of "John")

Hope this little tip will help anyone facing such problem.